# user disappeared, pw says user exists when trying to add, no such user when trying to mod in freebsd

Tags: freebsd

I was following the steps at http://bin63.com/how-to-setup-a-git-repository-on-freebsd to setup git on a server and when I went to setup the user with `pw useradd` the server said the user disappeared during config. Now when I try to do `pw useradd` it says the user already exists, but if I try `pw userdel` it says no such user, same with mod. The user doesn't show when I do `pw usershow -a` but is in `/etc/passwd` .

How do i get this user properly added?

Comment: Does the user exist in `/etc/shadow` too or only in `/etc/passwd`?

Comment: freebsd doesn't have shadow, but if I understand correctly the equivalent is master.passwd which it does show up in

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like your `/etc/pwd.db` and/or `/etc/spwd.db` got out of sync, try running: `pwd_mkdb /etc/master.passwd` (make backup first!).

Comment: I ran `pwd_mkdb` against `/etc/master.passwd` and now they are showing up. running it on `/etc/passwd` gave a corrupted entry line #e inappropriate file type or format. Doesn't `pwd_mkdb` create the passwd from master.passwd though?

Comment: @aron.duby sorry, you're right just against `/etc/master.passwd` only.

Comment: awesome, thanks! Still getting used to freebsd